# Left join or Select in select (SQL - Speed of query)

Tags: sql, select, left-join, inner-join

I have something like this:

```
SELECT CompanyId 
FROM Company
WHERE CompanyId not in
    (SELECT CompanyId 
     FROM Company 
     WHERE (IsPublic = 0) and CompanyId NOT IN 
         (SELECT ShoppingLike.WhichId 
          FROM Company 
          INNER JOIN 
          ShoppingLike ON Company.CompanyId = ShoppingLike.UserId 
          WHERE (ShoppingLike.IsWaiting = 0) AND
                (ShoppingLike.ShoppingScoreTypeId = 2) AND
                (ShoppingLike.UserId = 75)
          )
     )
```

It has 3 select, I want to know how could I have it without making 3 selects, and which one has better speed for 1 million record? "select in select" or "left join"?

Comment: If performance is an issue, try  each version on your data on your database on your hardware and see which is faster.

Comment: It has two question, I can't prepare left join, and for big data I can't test it because I haven't :(

Comment: if MS SQL do it for you, then don't worry because its optimizer will optimize your query. You can make index on companyId to help MS SQL to do query much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experiences are from Oracle. There is never a correct answer to optimising tricky queries, it's a collaboration between you and the optimiser. You need to check explain plans and sometimes traces, often at each stage of writing the query, to find out what the optimiser in thinking. Having said that:

- You could remove the outer `SELECT` by putting the entire contents of it's subquery `WHERE` clause in a `NOT(`...`)`.  On the face of it will prevent that outer full scan of Company (or it's index of CompanyId). Try it, check the output is the same and get timings, then remove it temporarily before trying the below. The `NOT()` may well cause the optimiser to stop considering an ANTI-JOIN against the ShoppingLike subquery due to an implicit OR being created.
- Ensure that CompanyId and WhichId are defined as `NOT NULL` columns.  Without this (or the likes of an explicit `CompanyId IS NOT NULL`) then ANTI-JOIN options are often discarded.
- The inner most subquery is not correlated (does not reference anything from it's outer query) so can be extracted and tuned separately.  As a matter of style I'd swap the table names round the `INNER JOIN` as you want ShoppingLike scanned first as it has all the filters against it. It wont make any difference but it reads easier and makes it possible to use a hint to scan tables in the order specified. I would even question the need for the Company table in this subquery.
- You've used `NOT IN` when sometimes the very similar `NOT EXISTS` gives the optimiser more/alternative options.

All the above is just trial and error unless you start trying the explain plan. Oracle can, with a following wind, convert between `LEFT JOIN` and `IN` `SELECT`.  1M+ rows will create time to invest.